# autoClose, placement on ngbDatePicker is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular14

```
    <input name="datepicker"
           class="form-control"
           ngbDatepicker
           #datepicker="ngbDatepicker"
           [autoClose]="'outside'" 
           [placement]="'bottom-right'" <Problem is here>
           [container]="'body'"
           (dateSelect)="onDateSelection($event)"
           [displayMonths]="2"
           [dayTemplate]="t"
           outsideDays="hidden"
           [startDate]="calendar.getToday()"
           style="display: none;">
```

If I don't use [placement], auto-close is working fine, which means that when I click outside the calendar window, it closes. However, if I use [placement], it's not working.

Angular 14
using
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^13.1.1",

I have tried to change this in `CSS` by removing [placement] no help ref below

```
.input-group{
  &.datepicker-right{
    ngb-datepicker{
      left: inherit !important;
      right: 0px;
    }
  }
}
```

I have changed the position of [placement] in the input, but it is still not helpful.

I have tried 'autoclose' and 'placement' because I need the calendar to be on the right side, not the left side. I am expecting it to close automatically when I click outside the calendar, and the calendar should be on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

As per my analysis, I was not able to reproduce the issue on stackblitz,  but I noticed you are setting an incorrect value for `placement` attribute.

[check the placement property of docs](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/datepicker/api#placement)

#### placement

> The preferred placement of the datepicker popup, among the possible
> values.
>
> The default order of preference is "bottom-start bottom-end top-start
> top-end"
>
> Please see the positioning overview for more details.
>
> Type: PlacementArray Default value: ['bottom-start', 'bottom-end',
> 'top-start', 'top-end'] — initialized from NgbInputDatepickerConfig
> service

Before:

```
...
[placement]="'bottom-right'" 
...
```

After:

```
...
[placement]="'bottom-end'" 
...
```

Alternative attempts to fix this can be

```
[placement]="['bottom-end']"
```

If its still not resolved, try to share the repo/stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging!

[example of working stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7wfkmf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-popup.html,src%2Fapp%2Fdatepicker-popup.ts,src%2Findex.html,angular.json)